# Filtrer QuerySet with type of ForeignKey

Tags: django, abstract-class, models, one-to-one

here are a few models to represent a shop products and information about who bought them.

```
class Bought(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User,default = None)

class Product(models.Model): # abstract

    price = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    bought = models.OneToOneField(Bought,default = None,blank=True,null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Prod1(Product):  # represents 1st kind of product

    #specific info about this Prod1...
```

If i need to list of everything bought by a User, i would use the ForeignKey and get
a QuerySet of Bought objects.
From this QuerySet, how can i differentiate what kind of product has been bought by the User ?( Prod1, Prod2...)

Comment: Why don't you create a table to store `kinds` of product and reference it as a `ForeignKey` in `Product` model, later while creating a product specify its kind, then you know which product is of which kind.

Comment: I think you should do something more simple, you can create only one model with all the fields, and add a field called kind_product with choices